# Chechout page error in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting the error whenever placed the order **"There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later"** and exception log says below.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: FavoredMinds_Vendor_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Window' in /home/jail/home/gemsclip/gemsclip-sites/gemsclip-live/app/Mage.php:594
```

Comment: PLease try after disabling this FavoredMinds_Vendor module and see if error goes.

Comment: glad it worked out.